# Upsert parent and children with EntityFramework

Tags: entity-framework-6, upsert

I find myself frequently wanting "Upsert" functionality in EntityFramework - I've got a disconnected graph of parent + children entities and I want to "upsert" the parent (and its children). By that I mean

- When the parent *doesn't* have an ID assigned (id = 0) I'd like to simply insert the parent and the children (auto assign IDs in both cases)
- When the parent *does* have a ID assigned, I'd like to replace the existing parent entity in the database (having the same ID) with the new one. In addition, any children associated with that parent should be removed (parent 'owns' the children). The children on the new parent should be inserted in their place (keeping the assigned ids).

This "mostly" works in that it retains the ID of the parent, but does not retain the IDs of the children (the children are assigned new IDs on each "upsert").

```cs
public void Upsert(ParentEntity parentEntity) {
    ParentEntity existing = DB.Parents.Find(parentEntity.Id);

    if (existing == null) {
        DB.Parents.Add(parentEntity);
    } else {
        var existingChildren = DB.Children.Where(m => m.ParentId == parentEntity.Id).ToArray();

        foreach (var child in parentEntity.Children) {
            child.ParentId = parentEntity.Id;
        }

        DB.Children.RemoveRange(existingChildren);
        DB.Children.AddRange(parentEntity.Children);

        DB.Entry(existing).State = EntityState.Detached;
        DB.Parents.Attach(parentEntity);
        DB.Entry(parentEntity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: PS I'm aware of `AddOrUpdate` but I don't want to use that (it's intended for migrations)

Comment: PPS: I've added a gist on Github which I'll update with the answer: https://gist.github.com/flakey-bit/eea47a27b605734104ece5531bb8fcb3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```cs
public void Upsert(ParentEntity parentEntity) {
    ParentEntity existing = DB.Parents.Find(parentEntity.Id);

    if (existing == null) {
        DB.Parents.Add(parentEntity);
    } else {
        var newChildKeys = new HashSet<int>(parentEntity.Children.Select(m => m.Id));

        var existingChildren = DB.Children.Where(m => m.ParentId == parentEntity.Id).ToArray();
        var existingChildrenKeys = new HashSet<int>(existingChildren.Select(m => m.Id));

        foreach (var existingChild in existingChildren) {
            if (newChildKeys.Contains(existingChild.Id)) {
                DB.Entry(existingChild).State = EntityState.Detached;
            } else {
                DB.Children.Remove(existingChild);
            }
        }

        foreach (var child in parentEntity.Children) {
            child.ParentId = parentEntity.Id;
            if (existingChildrenKeys.Contains((child.Id))) {
                DB.Children.Attach(child);
                DB.Entry(child).State = EntityState.Modified;
            } else {
                DB.Children.Add(child);
            }
        }

        DB.Entry(existing).State = EntityState.Detached;
        DB.Parents.Attach(parentEntity);
        DB.Entry(parentEntity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    SaveChanges();
}
```

Perhaps it can be improved on from a stylistic perspective / made more generic. The basic idea is

- Find the common keys across the entities (existing in database vs replacement entity)
- For *common* keys, detach the old entity, attach the new entity & mark as modified
- For keys that no-longer exist - remove the entity
- For new keys - add the entity

Answer (score -1):

This is something I use to get what I want. For my purpose it works great:

```
foreach (var metric in metrics)
{
    var added = context.Set(metric.GetType()).Add(metric);

    foreach (var dbEntityEntry in context.ChangeTracker.Entries())
    {
        //If these entities exist, don't add them.
        var metricContext = dbEntityEntry.Entity as MetricContext;
        if (metricContext != null)
        {
            var found = context.MetricContext.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Context == metricContext.Context);
            if (found != default(MetricContext))
            {
                dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Detached;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This detaches any entities that already live in the db, meaning they will not be processed.

Comment: This doesn't address the requirement of maintaining the IDs for the children where possible